# Obtain the cards > customFieldItems object from the boards end point

Tags: rest, api, trello

From a **single** [get request](https://developers.trello.com/reference#boardsboardid-1) to the *Boards* end point, is it possible to get the *customFieldItems* (i.e the custom field values associated with a card)?

When including parameters cards=all and customFields=all, the response returns:

- a cards object, but without any information relating to the custom fields;
- a customFields object, but with no way of linking it back to the card it is situated on

I could make additional requests for EACH card to the cards end point to obtain the information, but this would be a lengthy process and I would expect the response from the board end point to provide this information.

When inspecting the board .json file (from the browser) it includes the **customFieldItems** object within the **card** object. I am looking for the same information when requesting information from the boards end point.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Could you add in some code examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the [board](https://developers.trello.com/reference#boardsboardid-1) resource has both `cards` and `customFields` params. Custom Fields are defined at the board level, so that's what the `customFields` param returns. However, in your case, you want the [customFieldItems](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsidcustomfielditems) that are specific to a card.

For this case, you should refer to the [Cards Nested Resource](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cards-nested-resource), which includes the parameter you want, `card_customFieldItems`.

In short, you could use something like the following (substituting your own board id for `<id>`):

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/<id>?cards=all&card_customFieldItems=true'
```

The response will include an array of cards, each of which will contain a customFieldItems array, e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5acbd57f7160061ed10daa2c",
    "value": {
      "text": "High Priority"
    },
    "idCustomField": "5ab0f9f30c8780347a255463",
    "idModel": "5acbbe5d615f7dd1935b92f5",
    "modelType": "card"
  }
]
```